# Formulario se ve mal ¿Como hago para ordenar formulario en MDB(Material Design for Bootstrap)?

Tags: bootstrap, md-bootstrap

Estoy empezando con esto de **Bootstrap** y me gustaría saber de gente que tiene más experiencia, porque se me ve mal lo que copio de la página, sea de **MDB** o **Bootstrap**, *probé de las 2 formas con su respectiva instalación* y siempre lo que copio se me ve todo estirado de punta a punta del navegador como si fuese un formulario enorme.

Tal vez hay que editar algo que yo no se, *los modelos que copio no son premium*.

Así se me ve:

[image: Asi se me ve]

---

Ésta seria la vista correcta:

[image: La otra seria la vista correcta]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Esto se debe a que tu formulario ocupa un `width: 100%` quiere decir que abarca toda tu pantalla, la posible solución es que crees un contenedor padre para meter ese formulario, de la siguiente manera:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-form">
        <!-- Pega aqui tu formulario -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Y con un poco de css definimos el ancho que abarcara todo nuestro formulario:

```
.container-form {
            width: 600px;
            margin: auto;
        }
```

Y listo, si tienes alguna duda, por favor escribela.

Comment: Crear clases no es la mejor opción si trabajas con frameworks CSS. Puedes acudir directamente a las que vienen en la documentación.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @JheymanMejia Al menos con el conocimiento que tengo con bootstrap no hay una clase para definir un `width`. Por eso acudo a crear una clase extra. También para que el usuario que pregunto comprenda como es que funciona cada clase.

Comment: @JosuéMartínez para la version 3 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid y para la versión 4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/sizing/